# RxAndroid textview events called automatically before text change events

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I used rxandroid for debounce operation on an edittext search

I used

```
private void setUpText() {
        _mSubscription = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchStation)//
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)// default Scheduler is Computation
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
                .subscribe(getOps().getdata());
    }
```

and observer as

```
public Observer<TextViewTextChangeEvent> getdata()
    {

        return new Observer<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(TextViewTextChangeEvent onTextChangeEvent) {
//                stationsugession(onTextChangeEvent.text().toString());

                //here i called link to get the data from the server
            }
        };
    }
```

My problem is the link is called even before any edittext changes occurs.
And its not calling the textchange events.
Am i missing something
What am i doing wrong here. I am new to rxandroid and rxjava.

I used

```
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
```

**EDIT:**

It now works now, i was getting  a null pointer in my logic for getting list..
when i used the onError method and put a stacktrace i found the problem.

And if you want to skip the initial call then we should call **.skip(1)**
to your subscription object. [thanks to **Daniel Lew** ]

**The above code is working perfectly now**

Comment: What is the content of the TextViewChangeEvent?

Comment: TextViewTextChangeEvent is a class inside com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding for getting edittext events i guess

Comment: I know. What is returned when you call `onTextChangeEvent.text()` and log the result?

Comment: its only called once, the first time, i dont receive the changed events

Comment: Please add that piece of information to your question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`RxTextView.textChanges()` emits the current text value of the `TextView` before emitting any changes. See [the documentation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding/widget/RxTextView.java#L96).

If you want to only debounce the changes, then you should add `skip(1)`, which will ignore the initial emission:

```
_mSubscription = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchStation)
    .skip(1)
    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(getOps().getdata());
```

Comment: I have also used: RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchStation).filter { !it.text().isEmpty() }

Comment: In rxBinding2 (at least) you can use .skipInitialValue()

Comment: There is a nuance with "skip(x)" and configuration changes. Lets say you init RxTextView in activity onCreate. If you put "skip" before "debounce" and screen orientation is changed, then observer still fires. But if you put "skip" after "debounce" and orientation is changed - then observer skips initial value as expected.

Comment: @Andrew thankl you, +1 for you! I wondered why the orientation change is still calling the text change event, even if I used .skipInitialValue(). After switch the order to call debounce() first and then skip(1) it works like the expected behavior. We have to know that .skipInitialValue() is not callbale after debounce().

Comment: Calling skip not working for me, both before and after debounce